Parameter values in SQL statement are ignored in C# code
If have the following piece of C# code to write rows from a DataTable to my SQL Server table:
foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    string insertSql = GenerateInsertSql(tableName, dataTable.Columns, row);

    using SqlCommand insertCommand = new(insertSql, connection);

    foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        if (row[column] == DBNull.Value) 
        {
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{column.ColumnName}", DBNull.Value);
        }
    }

    foreach (SqlParameter param in insertCommand.Parameters)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Parameter: {param.ParameterName}, Value: {param.Value}, SqlValue: {param.SqlValue}");
    }

    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

The problem I'm struggling with is no matter what I try I'm not able to get null values in datetime columns where null values are allowed.
I tried it with adding command parameters but the result for columns containing a DBNull.Value is the default datetime value of '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'. As I said for this columns Null values are allowed and the are no constraints on the columns turning Null values into this default datetime value.
In the traceline written I can see that Value == {} and SqlValue == {Null}.
I also tried the same code with parameter value '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000, in that case both Value and SqlValue have this date value of '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000' but in the database after executing the insert command, the value is again '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'. So for me it looks like the parameters are ignored when executing the insert command.
From VS2022 debugger the DbParameterCollection:

Without the query it's a guess, but I assume you have a clause like YourDateTimeColumn = @YourDateTimeVariable and expecting NULL = NULL to evaluate to TRUE? It won't; it'll evaluate to UNKNOWN.

Not to mention the usual suggested reading: AddWithValue() is evil.

Don't use AddWithValue(). It let's ADO.Net try to infer the parameter type, and sometimes it's kind of bad at it. If it infer an sql datetime type (non-nullable), if will do the best it can to craft that kind of value.

can we see the value of insertSql for a sample row? or a truncated version of it?

This is a part of the insertSql command: CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Person (Id, LastName, Prefix, FirstName, Initials, Title, Gender, DateOfBirth, DateOfDeceased) VALUES ('37044876', 'Janssen', 'van', '', 'WE', 'Mr', 'V', '', '', );" The last two columns are of type datetime nulls allowed.

You do not use parameters in query. So, they are ignored.
